# Plot latitude and longitude

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to plot the latitude and longitude, but I'm getting an error message.

The code I'm using is the following

```
tweets <- searchTwitter('weather', n=1000,lang='en')
t <- twListToDF(tweets)
lat <- t[, c("latitude")]
lon <- t[, c("longitude")]
l.df <- data.frame(lat,lon)
l.na <- l.df[!is.na(l.df)]
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(l.na, aes(x=lon, y=lat,)) + geom_point(size=1.9, alpha=.02)
```

The error message is the following:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character

The values I'm getting in l.na are the following:

```
[1] "61.22"         "54.55508056"   "37.57"         "-5.14"         "37.78678264"   "29.42989111"   "32.79755357"   "30.26960519"   "29.75523769"  
[10] "51.04839287"   "30.1774"       "44.34334946"   "49.89034914"   "34.05161048"   "41.88804564"   "32.72791305"   "51.52027778"   "-31.77"
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error message?

Comment: ..Because `lon` and `lat` are of class character. Use `as.numeric()`

Comment: GGamba, I tried, but I'm getting the same error: ggplot(l.na, aes(x=as.numeric(lon), y=as.numeric(lat),)) + geom_point(size=1.9, alpha=.02)

Comment: ggplot only accepts a data.frame, and I'm pretty sure `l.df[!is.na(l.df)]` won't return one. Try `na.omit(l.df)`.

Comment: Thanks alistaire that worked

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the lat and lon columns into numeric.

`l.df$lat <- as.numeric(l.df$lat)`

`l.df$lon <- as.numeric(l.df$lon)`

`l.na <- l.df[!is.na(l.df)]`

Then apply the ggplot function:

```
ggplot(l.na, aes(x=lon, y=lat,)) + geom_point(size=1.9, alpha=.02)
```