# R latitude longitude visualization

Tags: r, geolocation

I'm trying to make a visualization of latitude and longitude values. Thanks to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462677/r-plot-latitude-and-longitude?noredirect=1#comment72067716_42462677) I managed to get the right values to be passed to ggplot. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter('weather', n=1000,lang='en')
t <- twListToDF(tweets)
lat <- t[, c("latitude")]
lon <- t[, c("longitude")]
l.df <- data.frame(lat,lon)
l.df <- na.omit(l.df)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(l.df, aes(x=l.df$lon, y=l.df$lat,)) + geom_point(size=10.9, alpha=.02)
```

The problem is that I'm getting a nearly empty plot. I'm saying nearly empty as there are some spots but are difficult to identify

How can I get a plot to display the map of the world and dots for the geo-location?

[image]

Comment: Your alpha value is very small. Have you tried to increase alpha value to something like 0.3? The other thing is that you probably need a data set for a map as well.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something more visible. Where do I find a data set for a map?

Comment: Look at the `leaflet` package. The [RStudio](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) github page has some good documentation on its use.

Comment: If you want a static map, you can try the `maps` package, for example. Alpha value stays between 0 and 1. You may want to play with the value and find the best for you.

Comment: You basically need two data sets. One for a map and one for your data point. When you draw a map, you can use `geom_map()` in `ggpot2` if you want. Then, you also use `geom_point()` for your twitter data. There are many SO questions which assist you. Search around, you will find some examples.

Comment: From the y axis on your plot, It looks like your lat and Lon values are factors and not numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `leaflet` package, you can simply call the map with your `data.frame` and pass in the values of latitude and longitude to create markers and get started:

```
library(leaflet)
yourMap <- leaflet(l.df) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircles(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat)
yourMap      # Prints the map
```

If you choose to use `leaflet`, be sure to install dependencies because the `%>%` is the piping operator from the `magrittr` package.

I suggested `leaflet` since, if you're looking to share your data and/or ever host it on a Shiny web server, they supply great documentation on the [RStudio "Leaflet for R"](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) Github page for its use, as I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. You are starting to know me too well. I'm getting an error message though: Error in validateCoords(lng, lat, funcName): addCircles requires numeric longitude/latitude values. I find it strange the numeric reference as this is working: ggplot(l.df, aes(x=l.df$lon, y=l.df$lat,)) + geom_point(size=10.9, alpha=.02)

Comment: I made it work after adding l.df$lat <- as.numeric(as.character(l.df$lat)) & l.df$lon <- as.numeric(as.character(l.df$lon)), but I get the dots but not map behind. Just a grey backgroud

Comment: Thanks for your help. Working properly now:     lon.m <- max(l.df$lat)
    lat.m <- max(l.df$lat)    
    leaflet(l.df) %>%
      addTiles() %>%  
      setView(-lon.m, lat.m, zoom = 1) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat)

Comment: Ah I am a dummy. I forgot you need to add a Tile layer to the leaflet to get it to render correctly. I didn't have a handy list of arbitrary lat/longs to test it. Sorry it took you a while to get it going! I will edit my answer.